# Error rebuilding reporting database Sitecore 7.5

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5, sitecore-analytics

I'm trying to rebuild the reporting database, And after applying the required configuration and when opening sitecore/admin/RebuildReportingDB.aspx and clicking on start button the following error appears in the log files:

```
    4100 2016:08:11 06:58:20 ERROR Exception when executing agent processing/taskAgent
Exception: System.IO.FileFormatException
Message: Element 'WorkItemType' does not match any field or property of class Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.ProcessingTask.
Source: MongoDB.Bson
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1.ReadFrom(BsonBuffer buffer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TaskQueue.TryGetNext(Guid taskIdBoundary, ProcessingTask& workItem)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.TasksAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Property 'WorkItemType' was added to Sitecore 8.0 and it could not be written by 7.5. Could you revisit TaskQueue in Mongo databases and check if all records there have property 'WorkItemType' or only one?

Comment: I believe my issue is that by mistake both 7.5 and the upgraded site 8.0 are connected to same mongodb! 

I can't find the "WorkItemType" property in the collections, I used robomongo and the following query and I went through all collections in the analytics and I could't find any record contain this field:
db.getCollection('Interactions').find({WorkItemType:{$exists: true}})

Comment: Can you try to clear HistoryTasks and TaskQueue collections from analytics and trackinglive database and rebuild again reporting db ?

Comment: I cleared those collections and tried using the sitecore 8 instance and sometimes data are transferred but if I tried again it clear the data and no aggregation is done, Also I have an aggregation processor but this processor is not triggered when rebuild the reporting database